# Hive memory setting for local task during map join

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm using a hdinsight cluster (hive version .13) to run some hive queries. One of the queries (query 7 from the TPCH suit) which launches a local task during map join fails due to insufficient memory (hive aborts it because the hashtable has reached the configured limit).

Hive seems to be allocating 1GB to the local task, from where is this size picked up and how can I increase it?

```
2015-05-03 05:38:19        Starting to launch local task to process map join;               maximum memory = 932184064
```

I assumed the local task should use the same heap size of the mapper, but it does not seem to be the case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Quite late on this thread.. but just for others who face the same issue.

The documentation does state that the local (child) JVM will have same size as that of map (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MapJoinOptimization), it does not seem to be the case. Instead, the JVM size is governed by `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` setting from hive-env.sh. So, in the case of original post from Shradha, I suspect the `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` is set to 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

This property controls it :

> yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts

This is the Application Manager jvm opts. Since local task runs on AM.

Can you also try this property :

> set hive.mapjoin.localtask.max.memory.usage = 0.999;

Comment: Thanks, this is set to 512m currently, I changed it to 2048 but it did not have any impact on the local task's maximum memory.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you try the property?

Comment: Thanks again, doesn't this property indicate the limit after which hive will abort the local task? I was more interested in knowing how to increase the maximum memory. The small table in my query takes up more that 1GB. Given that I am running these queries on clusters with 28GB ram, I was hoping that I could increase the max memory allocated. Another thing that I tried was set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size = 500000000 , but this will convert the query to common join instead of mapjoin which is not what i wanted. I will give it a try though and update this thread.

Comment: @ShradhaR did you fix this? can you update this thread with your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=512` or `HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Xmx512m` which can both be tweaked from `hadoop-env.sh`.

Note however that this might lead to unexpected behaviors for some jobs and you will probably have to play with

`mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.map.java.opts`

as well as

`mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` in the `mapred-site` config file in order to make sure that jobs remain stable.